# What is the difference between Concat and Concatenate?

Tags: sql, excel, google-sheets, join, concatenation

As I am learning data analysis, the words concat and concatenate came up in some of my lessons. I understand how to use them, but I cannot tell what makes the two different.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. [Help]

Comment: Where exactly have you seen 'concat' & what does it say about it there & how is it unclear what it means? If you "understand how to use them", how can you "not tell what makes the two different"? You are asking for yet more presentations for you to not understand & without saying how the words were used in the presentations you saw & without telling us how you were stuck understanding them.

Answer (score 3):

in google sheets (as you tagged your question) there are:

[image]

CONCAT can join only two things while CONCATENATE can join two or more things.

however, the best you can do is to know they exist and never ever use them. they are totally obsolete and with arrays you will face more pain with both of them than expected.

if you want to join stuff in google sheets use

```
JOIN
```

but more superior is textjoin because it is able to skip blank cells

```
TEXTJOIN
```

tho, the best way to join stuff is to use good old `&` especially when it comes to arrays. it's short, always works and it's short. example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A10&"-"&B2:B10)
```

wanna it shorter (?) drop the arrayformula and use index:

```
=INDEX(A2:A10&"-"&B2:B10)
```

wanna join A2 with C3 and D3:

```
=A2&C3&D3
```

wanna add delimiter:

```
=A2&"-"&C3&"-"&D3
```

or:

```
=JOIN("-"; A2; C3; D3)
```

or some other example:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-"; 1; A2:A5; G10)
```

also, it's worth noting that all of them (CONCAT, CONCATENATE, JOIN, TEXTJOIN) have a limit of 50000 characters.

to join larger datasets you will need to use QUERY like:

```
=QUERY(A1:A;;9^9)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what I am learning better with your explanation.

Comment: This is not true. CONCAT can join more than 2 things in Microsoft Excel.